# Installment calculation function

Tags: php, function, calculator

My existing codes are doing the calculation wrong, I can't find the right code.
For example, 14.75% commission, $100 transaction, 114.75 should be paid, while after the transaction it turns out to be $ 117.30.
I am sharing my codes below, how can I calculate correctly?

```
  $install = DB::getRow("SELECT installment FROM installments WHERE id='{$k}'");

        $montly  = round($mInfo->fPrice / (1 - str_replace(",", ".", $i) / 100) / $install->installment, 2);
        $total = round($mInfo->fPrice / (1 - str_replace(",", ".", $i) / 100), 2);
```

Comment: The `str_replace()` function returns a `string` . You need to cast this string to an `int` value - the `intval()`  or `floatval()` function is right for your problem.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please show me how you implemented the `floatval()` function in your code? What data types does `$mInfo-> fPrice` and `$install-> installment` return ??

Comment: // $montly  = round($mInfo->fPrice / (1 - intval($i) / 100) / $install->installment, 2);            // $total = round($mInfo->fPrice / (1 - intval($i) / 100), 2);             // $mInfo-> fPrice = 100$            // $install->installment = 3,6,9,12 instalment months          // $i = commission, 14.75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These codes will solve the problem my friend.

```
$montly = round(($mInfo->fPrice+(100*$i/100))/$install->installment,2); 
$total = round($mInfo->fPrice+(100*$i/100),2);
```